# Design: Initialising object with default associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm almost sure this will have been answered already but I can't find it!

**Requirement**

- I have two classes, `tournaments` and `teams`.
- Each `tournament` object `has_many` `teams`
- Most `tournaments` will have very similar `teams` so...
- I want to initialise each new `tournament` with a default set of `teams`, drawn from a static list.
- The default list may change but this should affect new `tournaments` only.

I can't come up with a design that seems optimal:

**Solution 1**

1. Have a `default_teams` class seeded with the default `teams` list.
2. For each new `tournament`; iterate through `default_teams` copying attributes to create new `teams`

This seems fairly easy to do but maintaining two essentially identical models doesn't seem very DRY.

**Solution 2**

1. Have a `tournament` flagged as default with the default `teams` associated.
2. Clone this `tournament` and its associations for each new `tournament`.

This seems like there is more scope for things to go wrong. I would need to exclude this default `tournament` from views and manage its permissions differently from the other `tournaments` in the same model. One model would essentially have two jobs and this doesn't seem quite right either.

**Question**

Is there a better way of doing this? I feel like this can't be a rare scenario but I can't find anyone else discussing best practices for it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got the question right. What is the static list of teams? Is it just plain text or do they exist in the db?

How about something along those lines

```
before_create :assign_default_teams

def assign_default_teams
  self.teams = [team_id1, team_id2, ...]
end
```

Since you mentioned initializing an object you could also use `after_initialize` instead of `before_create`. Make sure to pick the correct [callback](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) for your usecase.

Comment: The question is meant to be about approach rather than implementation but I do seem to struggle asking these questions in a clear way! I had assumed the list would be stored in the DB but open to suggestions.

Comment: Well my code snippet is I would guess the most common way of assigning defaults. And the most common approach are model callbacks. Just go for a m:n relation and you can maintain the teams and reuse them. So you don't have to maintain some sort of default tournament entry in the db or have a `default_teams` model. It could be also my lack of english knowledge that I miss sometimes subtle information.